# Picking a restaurant based off mood

Tags: python, random

Im trying to have python look at a list of restaurants I've made, each one being in a category (ex. McDonalds, Burger King, Canes are all in the american category). I would then like to input my mood (american, asian, chicken, etc.), and have python choose a place at random from that category. But so far it just chooses a place at random, no matter what I enter.

```
    import random
# create list of food choices
american = ['Mcdonalds', 'Burger King', 'Culvers', 'Wendys', 'KFC']
asian = ['Panda Express', 'Miso Japan', 'Sakura']
burger = ['Mcdonalds', 'Burger King', 'Culvers', 'Wendys']
chicken = ['Canes', 'KFC']
healthy = ['Panera']

rest = [american, asian, burger, chicken, healthy]
# pick random restaurant based off mood
print('What Mood Are You In?')
mood = input()
mood_choice = random.choice(rest)
final_choice = random.choice(mood_choice)
print(final_choice)
```

Comment: `mood` isn't actually used after `input()` - you may want to collect all your possible choices into a dict of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `dict`, storing the different categories as the keys and the list restaurants as the value. Then you can ask for user-input and select the appropriate key to get the list of restaurants which you can then feed to `random.choice` to get the desired result.

```
import random

food = {
    "american" : ['Mcdonalds', 'Burger King', 'Culvers', 'Wendys', 'KFC'],
    "asian" : ['Panda Express', 'Miso Japan', 'Sakura'],
    "burger" : ['Mcdonalds', 'Burger King', 'Culvers', 'Wendys'],
    "chicken" : ['Canes', 'KFC'],
    "healthy" : ['Panera']
}

mood = input('What Mood Are You In? ')
choices = food[mood.lower()]  # use str.lower in case input is 'Healthy'
mood_choice = random.choice(choices)
print(mood_choice)
```

Comment: This was such great help, thank you so much!